# Highlight specific paragraphs from documents

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, ocr, document-understanding

I have a bunch of documents in which I want to **highlight certain paragraphs/keyphrases**. I have a list of the most frequently appearing sentences and I want to search for these paragraphs/keyphrases in the document and if they appear, highlight them. The length of these paragraphs/keyphrases will be longer than 3-4 words. Below is an example doc:

[image: sample_image]

One approach I am currently trying (and failing) is using Pytesseract. These are the steps:

1. Use `image_to_data` function in Pytesseract to extract the words and their bounding boxes (bbox) from the document image.
2. From the extracted words, find the sentence using `re.search()`.
3. If there is a match, then store the words and their bbox coordinates in a dictionary and then use `cv2.rectangle()` to highlight them.

The issue with the above approach is the presence of duplicate words. For example in the above image if I want to highlight the sentence `Your acts or omissions`. For the words `Your`, `acts` and `omissions`, I am getting the correct coordinates but for the word `or`, since it is appearing once above the actual sentence (`property damage "or" personal and advertising`), the actual coordinate of the word `or` in the sentence `Your acts or omissions` is being replaced by the coordinates of `or` appearing in the sentence above `property damage "or" personal and advertising`.

This is happening for all duplicate keywords appearing. How can I solve this issue? I am also open to any other approach be it AI based or non AI based. Basically I need to highlight certain sentences occuring in a document, that's all!

Thanks in advance!